# Title: NextAuth.js - Conditional Use of CredentialsProvider and Avoiding Redirection

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, next-auth

I'm working on a Next.js project with NextAuth.js for authentication. I have multiple CredentialsProvider setups in my auth function, and I want to conditionally call one of them based on certain criteria when using the signIn function. Additionally, I'm trying to avoid redirection to the default sign-in page.

```js
// auth.ts
// ... (imports and other configurations)

export default async function auth(req, res) {
  const providers = [
    CredentialsProvider({
      id: "siwe",
      name: "Siwe",
      credentials: {
        // ... credentials for Siwe provider
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
      },
    }),
       CredentialsProvider({
      id: "admin-login",
      name: "AdminLogin",
      credentials: {
        user: { label: "User", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ];


  return await NextAuth(req, res, {
    providers,
      session: {
      strategy: "jwt",
    },
    jwt: {
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    },
    secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,
    callbacks: {
      async session({ session, token }) {
        //@ts-ignore
        session.address = token.sub;
        session.user.name = token.sub;
        return session;
      },
    },
  });
}
```

```js
signIn('admin-login', { callbackUrl: '/' });
```

Despite implementing this, I'm encountering issues, and the conditional provider is not being called as expected. Any suggestions on how to achieve this or insights into what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!